# Bleed on a geometric pattern

Tags: bleed

I have pattern set up but I'm not sure how to approach the bleed for the areas I've circled. If I extend the tips of the triangles - it will mess up the geometry of the pieces. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think what you have done is fine.  There's no way to make a bleed for those parts you circled, and it doesn't matter anyway since it would just be white paper.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the shapes, there would be no color bleed. It would just be white.

You will, of course, run the risk of those triangle points not being at the *exact* edge of the piece. But without a redesign, there's not much you can do about that. Ideally, you'd increase the size, or spread, of those triangle to include at least a little bleed.

Comment: I think I'll add a white border all around it. It's not ideal but I like the idea of an uneven white border (if the trim is imperfect) than the geometry of the pattern being messed with.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same situation you have in the blue and white triangles. As you have extended the blue to the bleed line, do the same with the white of the conflicting module:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**There is no perfect way to make a bleed on a pattern like this.**

The whole idea with a bleed is that it is physically impossible to make a 100% precise cut. So we let shapes continue outside the final size to account for some inaccuracy (often 3 mm).

The problem with your pattern is that you have shapes (all the triangles - not just the ones you circled) where one point needs to touch the edge of the paper. The cut must be precise on all four sides.

To see what would happen if the cut is not precise, you can just go to preview mode (w), select your whole pattern and try to nudge it a millimeter or two off-center like this:

[image]

As you see there are quite a few issues and I can't really see how you can handle it better than you already have.

So how big a problem is it? It depends on how picky you are and (among other things) on the kind of print you are making, how big it is (the smaller, the more precision is required) which paper it's printed on, how many pieces you order and the cutting method (is it cut or punched?).

If it worries you, you should ask your print provider about their advice. They might be able to reassure you that their accuracy is high enough or they might tell you that they can't take the responsibility for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's quite a small piece - 5in x 5in. I think it's cut rather than punched but I can check. 

I think I may just add a white border all around the pattern. I know there will be some issues with the white border not being even on all sides with an imperfect trim, - but at least the geometric pattern itself would be intact, so I think any issues with the white border would be less noticeable than if the trim affected the pattern itself.

Comment: Glad to help. I would maybe try a 1/4 inch margin.